# Deep Copy Constructor for Abstract Member and Class Function Pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, copy

This is a homework question.
There is a pure virtual constructor involved, assume the original is not null

```
BST::BST(const BST& original) {

root = original.root;
if (root != nullptr)
{
    root = new Node();
    root->setValue( original.root->getValue() );
    Node* subtree = root;
    Node* temp = original.root;
    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
        subtree = new Node();
        subtree->setLeft(temp->getLeft());
        temp = temp->getLeft();
        subtree = subtree->getLeft();
    }
    temp = original.root;
    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
        subtree = new Node();
        subtree->setRight(temp->getRight());
        temp = temp->getRight();
        subtree = subtree->getLeft();
    }

}
}
```

//clone

```
  BST::VIRTUALBinary* clone() {
  return (new BST(*this)); }
```

//call to main

```
VIRTUALBinary* orig = new BST();
VIRTUALBinary* copy = new BST();
copy = orig;
```

//deleting original, hoping to keep copy in main

```
delete orig;
```

The copy seems to share the same value as the original function, because it deletes itself everytime I delete the original. Any help would be appreciated, much thanks.

Comment: thank you, but i have actually tested using the clone function before as well. it still has the same result. can i assume that that means the rest of the code looks alright? i am almost coding this blind with help from stackoverflow and various websites

Answer (score 0):

You are only copying the pointers.

Use your `clone` method:

`VIRTUALBinary* copy = orig->clone()`